# Item with subitems appearing at once in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

In my presentation I have itemized list and sub-lists

I represent them as follows

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item {ONE}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item {B}
     \item{C}
     \end{itemize}
\item {two}
\end{itemize}
```

I use `[<+->]` so that item appear one by one.
I want that when `item{ONE}` appears, the sublist containing `\item {B}` and `\item{C}` should also apear.

What is happening now, each item and subitme appears one by one after each click.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<.->` (or just `<.>` if the inner list should only appear on slide one) as overlay specification for the inner list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item ONE
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
     \item B
     \item C
     \end{itemize}
\item two
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!! Exactly what is required